# How to tell auth0 im authenticated in req.rest file

Tags: rest, authentication, auth0

So I want to make a post request to my nextJS backend and the route i am making the req to a protected route so in my Rest client file (`req.rest`) I need to tell auth0 im authenticated but i do not know how to do that.

`req.rest`

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/video
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer cookie

{
    "title": "Video",
    "description": "Video description"
}
```

`api/video.js`

```
import { withApiAuthRequired, getSession } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import Video from "../../database/models/Video";

export default withApiAuthRequired(async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { user } = getSession(req, res);

      const newVideo = new Video({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        ownerId: user.sub,
      });

      await newVideo.save();

      res.json(newVideo);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I haven't really found a solution but I do have a  workaround which is to just make new page on the frontend for requests and send the requests from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Your API should determine if the user is authenticated by validating the bearer token value you are passing through the Authorization request header, you shouldn't need to pass additional data as separate parameters to authorize the API. If you do need additional data to determine if the user is authorized to consume the API, that should be included inside of the bearer token as a claim.

Comment: Yes. But what information do I pass in the Authorization header how do I grab the bearer token?

Comment: @SajawalHassan that depends on what type of authorization flow you are using. How are your users entering their credentials? Do you redirect them to a page served by your IdP and then redirect back to your app? If so, you should examine the payload of the response that returns the user to your application after they've entered their credentials. You probably have an access token in the body of the request.

Comment: It still says ```The user does not have an active session or is not authenticated```

Comment: If you are able to retrieve the access token your IdP is issuing during the authentication process, you can decode the token using https://jwt.io, That error message could result in failing to pass a bearer http header at all, or perhaps passing an expired or invalid access token as the bearer header. Do you see a value for the bearer header for the request to your API in the network tab of Chrome's f12 dev tools utility?